# Ranks and solution sets of homogeneous systems.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

> Given $A\in \mathbb{M}_{m\times n}^\mathbb{R},\ B\in \mathbb{M}_{n\times m}^\mathbb{R}$ such that $AB=I_m$.
>
> (a) Find $\rho(A),\rho(B)$ (the ranks of $A,B$) (SOLVED BY ME, $\rho(A)=\rho(B)=m$)
>
> (b) Show the solution set of $(BA)\underline{x}=\underline{0}$ is the same as the solution set of $A\underline{x}=\underline{0}$, and find $\rho(BA)$.

My attempt at (b):

I want to show they have the same dimension and one is contained within the other.

I was able to show Null$(A) \subseteq$ Null$(BA)$, but not $\dim $Null$(A)=$ $\dim $Null$(BA)$. This is where I need help!
I know that from the equality of the solution sets I can conclude $\rho(BA)=m$, so no need to explain that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have to check that:

$$\{x:Ax=0\}=\{x: BAx=0\}.$$

The inclusion $\subseteq$ is clear, because if $Ax=0$ then $BAx=B0=0.$ Now: suppose that $x$ is such that $BAx=0$; then

$$ABAx=A0=0 \Longrightarrow I_mAx=0,$$

since the identity matrix is invertible then $Ax=0$ so $x \in \{x:Ax=0\}$.